# Closed form for sum involving digamma?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function, poly-gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(n)$ be Euler's Gamma function and $\psi_0$ = $\frac{\Gamma'(n)}{\Gamma(n)}$ be the Digamma function.

Is there a closed form for
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi_0(n)}{n^2}=?$$

I've done some searching already and it would appear that it does not have a closed form.

Comment: Mathematica returns a closed form for the sum.

$\displaystyle \zeta (3) - \frac{\gamma \pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 2):

Use the alternative formulation for the Digamma function
$$\psi_0(n)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k$$
and Euler's
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=2\zeta(3)$$
where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ are the Harmonic numbers and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Thus, we find
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\psi_0(n)}{n^2}&=-\gamma\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^2}
+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{H_n-\frac1n}{n^2} \\
&=-\gamma\zeta(2)+2\zeta(3)-\zeta(3) \\
&=\zeta(3)-\gamma\zeta(2).
\end{align*}